# GitLab CI Android SDK not found

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using a modified Docker image from jangrewe to automate the build. The SDK path should already defined in the Docker image using `ENV ANDROID_HOME "/sdk"` but GitLab showed me this error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.`
So I modified my .gitlab-ci.yml file like this:

```
image: tbremer19/wercker-container-android

before_script:
  - export ANDROID_HOME="/sdk"

build:
  script:
    - chmod 777 *
    - sudo ./gradlew assembleBetaDebug --stacktrace
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/apk/app-beta-debug.apk
```

but still get this error. Did anyone of you experience this? I tried to set ANDROID_HOME as an environment variable twice but apparently that didn't help...

Comment: This post, written by an Android developer of Snapchat, might help you: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/ He explains how to build and test an Android app with GitLab CI, gives the code you need for .gitlab-ci.yml and break it into parts, explained one by one.

Answer (score 3):

Use environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/sdk".
ANDROID_HOME environment variable is deprecated in newer version of android sdk.

For Reference:
[Android SDK environment variables](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables#:%7E:text=SDK%20environment%20variables-,ANDROID_SDK_ROOT,-Sets%20the%20path)

Comment: In reference I only see that ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is deprecated, not ANDROID_HOME